# request a new google map on zoom event

Tags: android, google-maps

I can't understand how works the `GoogleMap` object.

My problem is related with the zoom. When the user zooms on the map, the image become unreadable because is too "pixelled". So what I want, is force the downloading of a new zoomed map, when the zoom value become very big.

How can I do it?

Comment: I think GoogleMap already do that. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#zoom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DeividiCavarzan commented, Google Map already does this.

The heavily pixeled view you're seeing is a "preview" of the area that is not loaded yet.

It it basically the stretch previous image that was there, but since you're zooming, it's invalidated and a download is made to get a more refine image.

If your network connection is bad, then this pixeled image will show for a while, yes. But nothing can be done to avoid that: you need offline map or connectivity.